# Why does a <p> element overflow a <span> element?

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand inline and block level elements fully.

Can someone please explain the below behavior?

```css
p {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

span {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <span>
        <p>hello</p>
    </span>
</body>
```

Why is the p element overflowing the span?

to my understating block-level elements take the full width of their container.

the container of the p element is the `span`.
but the p element is taking the full width of the screen.

why is causing this behavior?

Comment: Because `<span>` is not _container (block) element_

Comment: because it is an invalid markup. `span` is an inline element and only allows inline-content. `p` is a block-level element and as such not an allowed child element of a span. An inline-element by default has no defined width. It's width is calculated to `fit-content`. The `p` however has a width of 100% which means 100% of the parent's width. In this case it would be 100% of undefined and as such gives an error that causes an overflow.

Comment: the linked question tells what the behavior is, but doesn't explain the theory behind it. my question is why does the <p> element overflow the span element?

Comment: The p element in this case, is taking the width of the span's parent, which is body is this case. is there a reason why it does that?

Comment: None of this matters because such HTML is invalid. A `<span>` element cannot contain a `<p>` element.

Comment: @Rob - You could replace the `<span>` element with an `<a>` element. You'd get exactly the same rendering behaviour, and the HTML would be valid.

Comment: @Alohci One can change his markup in all kinds of ways but it's not part of his question and, therefore, why I brought it up.

Answer (score 1):

From the [CSS 2 specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#anonymous-block-level):

> When an inline box contains an in-flow block-level box, the inline box
> ... is broken around the block-level box ..., splitting the inline box
> into two boxes ..., one on each side of the block-level box(es). The line
> boxes before the break and after the break are enclosed in anonymous
> block boxes, and the block-level box becomes a sibling of those
> anonymous boxes.

So the `<p>` element isn't *overflowing* the `<span>` element, it's *breaking* it in two.

Comment: It doesn't matter because it's invalid HTML.

Comment: Whether the HTML is valid or not is irrelevant. Browsers don't care whether HTML is valid or not. The behaviour is entirely mechanical.

Comment: That's an amateur's  comment that encourages bad behavior. I am shocked you would say such a thing. You should know better than that.

Comment: Nope. The OP is asking about how to understand browser behaviour. I'm not here to police their authoring practices.

Comment: @Rob what you suggest is that the browser should stop working when there is an invalid code but it's not the case. The browser will always *try* to produce an output whatever the code you give and a lot of developers spent hours implementing such behavior so it doesn't hurt if we explain the effort done behind the scenes. There are a lot of cases where an invalid code produce a strange result that has an explanation somewhere.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I said no such thing. I said incorrect markup is wrong and should be corrected and not used. Any attempts to help someone with incorrect/invalid markup only encourages bad behavior and bad code. Where in all that do you get that I said a browser should stop working?

Comment: So I figured this out. In this case the answer to the question can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block
meaning that the containing block of the p element is actually the body in this case.